# Why didn't the Lambent Wretches attack the Locust?

Tags: gears-of-war

In the first *Gears of War,* during the mission at the Lethia Imulsion Facility, we are introduced to the [Lambent Wretches](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Lambent_Wretch).  These creatures were different from the wretches seen previously in the game, as their exposure to imulsion made them glow, and they were more volatile (exploding shortly after they were killed).  In this game, we see them apparently fighting alongside the Locust Horde.

In *Gears of War 2,* however, we learn that the Locust have been fighting a civil war against Lambent Locust (and, in *Gears of War 3,* we learn that this war has been going on [for many years](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Lambent_War); well before the [Emergence Day](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Emergence_Day)).

Given the fact that the Locust clearly could not peacefully coexist with the Lambent, what kept the Lambent Wretches from attacking the Locust during the events of the first game?

Comment: I don't think we learn much from the first game regarding them or the civil war. I no longer have the games to replay the first game and see how often you run into the Lambents or how "intertwined" the two were as you faced them, but I would chalk it up to them being mid transformation (given how close they were to the surface) and maybe even confusion as they were the first to reach the surface of Sera... good catch though...